# Are inotify event reads guaranteed not to be split across buffers?

Tags: linux, inotify

All of the code examples for inotify do something like this:

```
#define EVENT_SIZE  (sizeof (struct inotify_event))

#define BUF_LEN        (1024 * (EVENT_SIZE + NAME_MAX + 1))

char buf[BUF_LEN];

num = read(_fd, buf, BUF_LEN);
```

So presumably this allows for a single `read()` call to return up to 1024 events.

What if there are actually more events than that in the queue? Will inotify guarantee to return a whole number of events, even if that means a short read? Or will inotify split an event across two reads?

Comment: Frankly, that seems like an unnecessarily huge buffer. I suspect all the sample code out there is just copying other sample code. I'd like to reduce that buffer size in my own application if possible.

Comment: To the extent you might be interested in considering other alternatives besides a C/stdlib API, here's a great article (from the late, great, extremely lamented "Linux Journal"): [Linux Filesystem Events with inotify](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/linux-filesystem-events-inotify).  PS: To answer your question: if the #/pending events exceeds your buffer, then read will return "0"; you won't get *ANY* events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `man` page for [`inotify`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify):

> The behavior when the buffer given to read(2) is too small to return
> information about the next event depends on the kernel version: in
> kernels before 2.6.21, read(2) returns 0; since kernel 2.6.21, read(2)
> fails with the error EINVAL. Specifying a buffer of size
>
> sizeof(struct inotify_event) + NAME_MAX + 1
>
> will be sufficient to read at least one event.

So historically it rounded *down*, and at this point, it sounds like it would fail with `EINVAL`.

Comment: Hmmm. OK, so we know it will refuse to give a short read. I suppose that implies that it won't split an event across reads either. I think this is close to an answer we'll get without reading the source code.